# Convert String input to Double and avoid java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: java, string, android-studio, double, numberformatexception

I need to convert a String input to a double so that I can create a toast pop-up if the input is out of a certain range (using if statements with < and > operators).
Edit: input1 is a user input saved in room

I've tried converting the String to a double using this code 
`Double d = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(input1));`
but this comes up with the error
"Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "com.example.mysugartracker.Input1@d89771f""
Within this class, I retrieve input1 and use the inputs to fill a recyclerView, which leads me to believe that retrieving input1 is not the problem, but instead the method of converting it to a double. (*Though I am only a beginner at using android studio so I could be wrong*)

Tabbed.java (class where the pop-up is displayed)

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        mInputViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(InputViewModel.class);
        if (requestCode == INPUT_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Input1 input1 = new Input1(data.getStringExtra(input.EXTRA_REPLY));
            mInputViewModel.insert(input1);
            ** Double d = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(input1)); **
            //display pop-up if blood is above target
            if (d > 8.0) {
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        R.string.PopupHigh,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            //display pop-up if blood is below target
            if (d < 4.0) {
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        R.string.PopupLow,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        R.string.empty_not_saved,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
        }
    public static final int INPUT_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
```

input1.java (entity class where the user input is saved)

```
public class Input1 {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;
    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "input1")
    private String mInput1;

    Input1(@NotNull String input1) {this.mInput1 = input1;}
    public String getInput1() {return this.mInput1;}

    //getter for id
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    //setter for id
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

I've marked the problematic code with **

I need a different way to convert the String input to a double without causing a java.lang.NumberFormatException or a way to avoid this error.

Comment: Your problem is getting the text out of the `Input1` object.  Does the `Input1` class have a method for getting the text?  If so, you'll need to call it.

Comment: What is `Input1`?

Comment: @user207421 Input1 is user input that is saved in a room database (i made the database using this tutorial [https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#11]

Comment: It is a class whose code was omitted from your original question.

Comment: @user207421 yes, I'm aware. When I realised my mistake I edited my question to add in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which methods are available on Input1, but your problem will be solved by simply calling the method that gives you the value. `String.valueOf(input1)` returns the String representation of the object, which means it simply calls the `toString()` method, and in your case Input1 does not override toString therefore it is `Object.toString()` that is being called.

Change it to something like this:

`Double d = Double.parseDouble(input1.getValue());`

Or, alternatively, implement `Input1.toString()`:

**UPDATED** with solution based on comments:

```
public class Input1 {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;
    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "input1")
    private String mInput1;

    Input1(@NotNull String input1) {this.mInput1 = input1;}
    public String getInput1() {return this.mInput1;}

    //getter for id
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    //setter for id
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    // Just add this method to you Input1 class
    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return mInput1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried changing the line to ```Double d = Double.parseDouble(input1.getValue());``` as you suggested, but I get the error ```Cannot resolve method 'getValue()'```. I've edited my question to show the input1 class, which is a room entity.

Comment: @BreannaJury So *implement* `getValue()` in your `Input1` class.

Comment: @user207421 I've changed the first line of my Input1.java class to ```public class Input1 implements getValue(){``` but it comes up with the error `Cannot resolve symbol 'getValue'`

Comment: ```
public String getValue() {
    return mInput1;
}
```

Comment: Or use your existing `getInput1()` method.